# Distinguish between [apache-velocity] and [velocity]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

Currently, these two tags are both described as tags for [Apache Velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/):

- [velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/velocity)

  [image]
- [apache-velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-velocity)

  [image]

Some questions in the [velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/velocity) tag are not related to Apache Velocity.

A good solution would be:

- Keep [apache-velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-velocity) for questions about Apache Velocity.  Move all related questions to this tag.
- Change the description of the [velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/velocity) tag to be about the physical term "velocity", keeping relevant questions there.

Comment: *Velocity* is also [a thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_(software_development)) in [Scrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(software_development)#Velocity) (though likely off-topic).